# Drupal trial account development

Tags: drupal, authentication, profile, account, trial

I am creating a website where you can create an account with your name and email. When this is done, you get a 30 day trial. From this point, you can 'upgrade' your account by supplying more information.

When you do not update your information after 30 days, your account is suspended.

Can anyone give me some tips how to do this ?
So:
- Create profile with email and name (easy), indicator is stored in db that you are trial user.
- When you log in, you can extend your profile with extra information. indicator that you are full user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always write your own module to do it, but my recommendation is using the [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) module, and using several user roles.

- Any new user gets a "trial" role he registers.
- Create the needed fields in the user profile
- Create a rule which will change the user's role in case the field is filled (rule triggeres whenever user profile is updated).
- Create a rule with cron that executes once a day, to suspend user account, and probably to send him a notification before doing so.

Comment: That was what I had in mind, I would use the profile module, but then I need 2 sepperate profiles. I actually want one profile, when filling in only needs some fields, when created, asks for more mandatory fields. You think this will be possible without a custom module ?

Comment: I am not certain 100%, but I think so.